# In MySQL, why is it safe to turn off innodb_support_xa for single threaded updates?

Tags: mysql, innodb

In MySQL's docs the following is said about the `innodb_support_xa` option:

> Enables InnoDB support for two-phase commit in XA transactions, causing an extra disk flush for transaction preparation. This setting is the default. The XA mechanism is used internally and is essential for any server that has its binary log turned on and is accepting changes to its data from more than one thread. **If you turn it off, transactions can be written to the binary log in a different order from the one in which the live database is committing them.** This can produce different data when the binary log is replayed in disaster recovery or on a replication slave. Do not turn it off on a replication master server unless you have an unusual setup where only one thread is able to change data.
>
> **For a server that is accepting data changes from only one thread, it is safe and recommended to turn off this option to improve performance for InnoDB tables.** For example, you can turn it off on replication slaves where only the replication SQL thread is changing data.

However, from my understanding from reading on the infamous [group commit bug](http://kristiannielsen.livejournal.com/12408.html), 2PC is used to guarantee that the transaction log and the binlog contain the same set of transactions, while the `prepare_commit_mutex` is responsible for ensuring the same order.

With `prepare_commit_mutex`, the writing to the transaction log and the binlog are already serialized, then what's the difference between multi-threaded and single-threaded updates?

On the other hand, even if there is only one thread that can change data, without 2PC, if a crash occurs after a transaction is written to the binlog, but before it's written to the transaction log, how is Innodb going to deal with this situation in recovery? In theory it can simply execute the outstanding transaction in the binlog, just as what the slaves do, but I doubt Innodb actually does that, because otherwise why do we need 2PC at all?

I'm not familiar at all with the internals of MySQL, so please forgive me if I'm terribly wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with...

http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.com/2009/08/great-performance-effect-of-fixing.html

Before InnoDB Plugin 1.0.4, it was like:

```
obtain mutex
  write innodb log and fsync, for prepare-phase (skip if innodb_support_xa=0)
  write binlog (fsync as appropriate if sync_binlog > 0)
  write innodb log and fsync, for commit-phase
release mutex
```

On and after InnoDB Plugin 1.0.4 (and MySQL 5.5), it is now:

```
write innodb log and fsync, for prepare-phase (skip if innodb_support_xa=0)
obtain mutex
  write binlog (fsync as appropriate if sync_binlog > 0)
  write innodb log, for commit-phase
release mutex
fsync innodb log, for commit-phase
```

As you can see, in the new version, nothing (except in case `sync_binlog` > 0) is fsync'd in the critical section. That way, group commit now works and ensures far better concurrent throughput.

For instance, with the previous "broken" version, if you had 100 threads concurrent commits, all fsyncs were serialized and you would get 100 fsyncs for prepare and another 100 fsyncs for commit. Therefore group commit was completely broken.

Now with the newer implementation, fsyncs are grouped depending on the concurrency of transactions, while ensuring operation ordering between innodb log and binlog. It also means that if there's only one thread, there's no performance gain.

As to your question that, when crash occurs after a transaction is written to the binlog, but before it's written to the transaction log - I'm on the same page as you.

If the server crashed before the final step, there's a slight chance that you have a discrepancy between innodb log and binlog (either one could be ahead of the other), but it is guaranteed that **you have all the information on what to examine** in the innodb log, as it is recorded in the prepare-phase.

However, what to do with the uncommitted is still nondeterministic. For instance, unless `sync_binlog = 1` there's a chance that a slave received the data but not fully fsync'd the binlog on the master yet. You can't just redo the failed transaction as it may have already run on one of the slaves.

Which also means, the binlog could be shorter than the innodb log, returning "The binary log [file_name] is shorter than its expected size." as described in the official doc, and you have to rebuild the slave from scratch. Not very human friendly.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-log.html

As consistency in terms of operation ordering is guaranteed independent of the `innodb_support_xa` setting (which contradicts what's said in the official doc on `innodb_support_xa`, maybe because it was written about the stock innodb 5.0.3 far before the concurrency fix), and consistency between innodb log on the master and relay log on the slave is not strictly guaranteed even with `innodb_support_xa`, I don't see any point in using `innodb_support_xa`. It's scary to not follow the official recommendation, though, however it seems stale and wrong in many points.

I'm wondering if there's any correlation between the `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` setting and the `innodb_support_xa` behavior when the former is set to 2 or 0.

One practical way of thinking is that, failover to the slave is safe - after all, the failed transaction was something that you wanted to get done - but never fail-back to master, as there might be some discrepancy in the data. You need to fully copy the data from the slave, before you make the master a new slave. In other words, when the master crashed, trust the slave from then on - that way, you don't need to mess with innodb log for crash recovery.

Also note that MySQL 5.5 supports semi-synchronous replication, along the same line as "trust the slave" - thought you might be interested.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-semisync.html

Comment: @Sebas comment is a little vague, according to MySQL docs: "innodb_support_xa is deprecated and will be removed in a future MySQL release. InnoDB support for two-phase commit in XA transactions is always enabled as of MySQL 5.7.10" So it is deprecated, but only because it will always be on.