# MySQL: Very slow update/insert/delete queries hanging on "query end" step

Tags: mysql, performance, replication, innodb

I have a large and heavy loaded mysql database which performs quite fast at times, but some times get terribly slow. All tables are **InnoDB**, server has **32GB of RAM** and **database size is about 40GB**.

Top 20 queries in my `slow_query_log` are `update`, `insert` and `delete` queries and I cannot understand why they are so slow (up to 120 seconds sometimes!)

Here is the most frequent query:

```
UPDATE comment_fallows set comment_cnt_new = 0 WHERE user_id = 1;
```

Profiling results:

```
mysql> set profiling = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> update comment_fallows set comment_cnt_new = 0 where user_id = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (2.77 sec)
Rows matched: 18  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> show profile for query 1;
+---------------------------+----------+
| Status                    | Duration |
+---------------------------+----------+
| starting                  | 0.000021 |
| checking permissions      | 0.000004 |
| Opening tables            | 0.000010 |
| System lock               | 0.000004 |
| init                      | 0.000041 |
| Searching rows for update | 0.000084 |
| Updating                  | 0.000055 |
| end                       | 0.000010 |
| query end                 | 2.766245 |
| closing tables            | 0.000007 |
| freeing items             | 0.000013 |
| logging slow query        | 0.000003 |
| cleaning up               | 0.000002 |
+---------------------------+----------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am using master/server replication, so the binary log is enabled. I've fallowed one advice I've found on the internet and set `flush_log_at_trx_commit` to `0` but it did not make any difference:

```
mysql> show variables like '%trx%';
+-------------------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                             | Value |
+-------------------------------------------+-------+
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit            | 0     |
| innodb_use_global_flush_log_at_trx_commit | ON    |
+-------------------------------------------+-------+
```

The table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `comment_fallows` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `part_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `request_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment_cnt` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `comment_cnt_new` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_comment_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`last_comment_date`),
  KEY `part_id` (`part_id`),
  KEY `last_comment_date` (`last_comment_date`),
  KEY `request_id` (`request_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `comment_fallows_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `comment_fallows_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`part_id`) REFERENCES `fanfic_parts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `comment_fallows_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`request_id`) REFERENCES `requests` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2239419 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And all the innodb settings (server has 32 GB of RAM):

```
mysql> show variables like '%innodb%';
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name                             | Value                  |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| have_innodb                               | YES                    |
| ignore_builtin_innodb                     | OFF                    |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing                  | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing_method           | estimate               |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index                | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index_partitions     | 1                      |
| innodb_additional_mem_pool_size           | 16777216               |
| innodb_autoextend_increment               | 8                      |
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode                  | 1                      |
| innodb_blocking_buffer_pool_restore       | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances              | 1                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_restore_at_startup     | 0                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_shm_checksum           | ON                     |
| innodb_buffer_pool_shm_key                | 0                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                   | 21474836480            |
| innodb_change_buffering                   | all                    |
| innodb_checkpoint_age_target              | 0                      |
| innodb_checksums                          | ON                     |
| innodb_commit_concurrency                 | 0                      |
| innodb_concurrency_tickets                | 500                    |
| innodb_corrupt_table_action               | assert                 |
| innodb_data_file_path                     | ibdata1:10M:autoextend |
| innodb_data_home_dir                      |                        |
| innodb_dict_size_limit                    | 0                      |
| innodb_doublewrite                        | ON                     |
| innodb_doublewrite_file                   |                        |
| innodb_fake_changes                       | OFF                    |
| innodb_fast_checksum                      | OFF                    |
| innodb_fast_shutdown                      | 1                      |
| innodb_file_format                        | Antelope               |
| innodb_file_format_check                  | ON                     |
| innodb_file_format_max                    | Antelope               |
| innodb_file_per_table                     | ON                     |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit            | 0                      |
| innodb_flush_method                       |                        |
| innodb_flush_neighbor_pages               | area                   |
| innodb_force_load_corrupted               | OFF                    |
| innodb_force_recovery                     | 0                      |
| innodb_ibuf_accel_rate                    | 100                    |
| innodb_ibuf_active_contract               | 1                      |
| innodb_ibuf_max_size                      | 10737401856            |
| innodb_import_table_from_xtrabackup       | 0                      |
| innodb_io_capacity                        | 10000                  |
| innodb_kill_idle_transaction              | 0                      |
| innodb_large_prefix                       | OFF                    |
| innodb_lazy_drop_table                    | 0                      |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout                  | 120                    |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog            | OFF                    |
| innodb_log_block_size                     | 512                    |
| innodb_log_buffer_size                    | 8388608                |
| innodb_log_file_size                      | 268435456              |
| innodb_log_files_in_group                 | 3                      |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir                 | ./                     |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct                | 90                     |
| innodb_max_purge_lag                      | 0                      |
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups                | 1                      |
| innodb_old_blocks_pct                     | 37                     |
| innodb_old_blocks_time                    | 0                      |
| innodb_open_files                         | 300                    |
| innodb_page_size                          | 16384                  |
| innodb_purge_batch_size                   | 20                     |
| innodb_purge_threads                      | 1                      |
| innodb_random_read_ahead                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_read_ahead                         | linear                 |
| innodb_read_ahead_threshold               | 56                     |
| innodb_read_io_threads                    | 8                      |
| innodb_recovery_stats                     | OFF                    |
| innodb_recovery_update_relay_log          | OFF                    |
| innodb_replication_delay                  | 0                      |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout                | OFF                    |
| innodb_rollback_segments                  | 128                    |
| innodb_show_locks_held                    | 10                     |
| innodb_show_verbose_locks                 | 0                      |
| innodb_spin_wait_delay                    | 6                      |
| innodb_stats_auto_update                  | 1                      |
| innodb_stats_method                       | nulls_equal            |
| innodb_stats_on_metadata                  | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_sample_pages                 | 8                      |
| innodb_stats_update_need_lock             | 1                      |
| innodb_strict_mode                        | OFF                    |
| innodb_support_xa                         | ON                     |
| innodb_sync_spin_loops                    | 30                     |
| innodb_table_locks                        | ON                     |
| innodb_thread_concurrency                 | 16                     |
| innodb_thread_concurrency_timer_based     | OFF                    |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay                 | 10000                  |
| innodb_use_global_flush_log_at_trx_commit | ON                     |
| innodb_use_native_aio                     | ON                     |
| innodb_use_sys_malloc                     | ON                     |
| innodb_use_sys_stats_table                | OFF                    |
| innodb_version                            | 1.1.8-rel25.1          |
| innodb_write_io_threads                   | 8                      |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+
92 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've been struggling with this problem for weeks and would be very greatfull for any advice on how to solve this problem.

Why could my `update`, `insert` and `delete` queries be so slow on `query end` step?

**update**

I have disabled query cache, but `update`, `insert` and `delete` queries are still very very slow (nothing changed)

```
show variables like '%cache%';
+------------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name                | Value                |
+------------------------------+----------------------+
| binlog_cache_size            | 4194304              |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size       | 32768                |
| have_query_cache             | YES                  |
| key_cache_age_threshold      | 300                  |
| key_cache_block_size         | 1024                 |
| key_cache_division_limit     | 100                  |
| max_binlog_cache_size        | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size   | 18446744073709547520 |
| metadata_locks_cache_size    | 1024                 |
| query_cache_limit            | 16777216             |
| query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096                 |
| query_cache_size             | 0                    |
| query_cache_strip_comments   | OFF                  |
| query_cache_type             | ON                   |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF                  |
| stored_program_cache         | 256                  |
| table_definition_cache       | 400                  |
| table_open_cache             | 2048                 |
| thread_cache_size            | 8                    |
+------------------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: When you run that query with id instead of user_id "UPDATE comment_fallows set comment_cnt_new = 0 WHERE id = 1" would it have the same latency?

Comment: @Pinchy, yes. In fact, it's even slower.

Comment: @SilverLight which version of MySql?

Comment: Have you tried to [pause replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-administration-pausing.html), just to see if this is a replication lag problem? Have also a look at [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18432/extremely-slow-myisam-slave-updates) for some references to the [Percona Toolkit](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit) software, which may be useful to verify master and replica data consistency.

Comment: @CristianPorta Server version: 5.5.21-55-log

Comment: @Enzino, actially, this problem occurs on MASTER server, I do not think that pausing the replication will do any good...

Comment: Is the server configured to autocommit? I think i have the exact same problem as you. Im runing mysql 5.6.11

Answer (score 13):

Try setting values:

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT (for non-windows machine)
innodb_buffer_pool_size=25GB (currently it is close to 21GB)
innodb_doublewrite=0
innodb_support_xa=0
innodb_thread_concurrency=0...1000 (try different values, beginning with 200)
```

References:

[MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html) for description of different variables.

[MySQL Server Setting Tuning](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/files/presentations/UC2007-MySQL-Server-Settings-Tuning.pdf)

[MySQL Performance Optimization basics](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/)

Hope it helps...

Comment: didnt work for me. Still get query end. Could it that i dont have any swap disk on the server? Im running windows server...

Comment: Great, it works. For smaller installations, you would probably need less innodb_thread_concurrency and innodb_buffer_pool_size, but in general this advice works.

Comment: Are these settings safe for production? I don't think so.

Comment: it's a reckless dangerous and irrelevant advice. I'm surprised it's even upvoted.

Comment: Am I mistaken, 25GB pool size means 25 GB of ram ?
Do you guys all run on servers with that intense amount of ram ?

Comment: @akuzmisky For innodb_doublewrite https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86636/when-is-it-safe-to-disable-innodb-doublewrite-buffering for innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2 https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12611/is-it-safe-to-use-innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit-2 and for innodb_support_xa=0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067093/in-mysql-why-is-it-safe-to-turn-off-innodb-support-xa-for-single-threaded-updat 

Basicaly this is not safe but having only innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2 and innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT is quite fair for performance. innodb_doublewrite = 0 is danger

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be a bug with how MySQL handles the query cache which causes similar behaviour (see http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28382).

What is basically happening is that the cache needs to be updated following any query that modifies data (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE). With a large cache it is taking a long time to do this, if the cache is smaller then its faster.

So the work-around until the engine is fixed is to decrease the cache size.

Comment: joocer, thank you for your answer. I had query cache of 512 Mb. When I disabled it, things indeed became a lot faster. But INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE queries are still very slow.

Comment: @SilverLight, just to confirm, are the queries still slow on the "query end" step or has the performance of the other steps changed at all?

Answer (score 1):

It may be a problem of hardware if you are using DELL server. 
I resolved this command.

> /opt/dell/srvadmin/bin/omconfig storage vdisk action=changepolicy
>   controller=0 vdisk=0 writepolicy=fwb

Answer (score 0):

Try starting tuning your `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` according the `innodb_buffer_pool_size`

Firs of all I think you can increase significantly your `innodb_buffer_pool_size`...

**[innodb_buffer_pool_instances sysvar](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances)**

> The size in bytes of the memory buffer InnoDB uses to cache data and
>   indexes of its tables. The default value is 128MB, increased from a
>   historical default of 8MB. The maximum value depends on the CPU
>   architecture, 32-bit or 64-bit. For 32-bit systems, the CPU
>   architecture and operating system sometimes impose a lower practical
>   maximum size.
>
> The larger you set this value, the less disk I/O is needed to access
>   data in tables. On a dedicated database server, you may set this to up
>   to 80% of the machine physical memory size. Be prepared to scale back
>   this value if these other issues occur...

Then you can tune the `innodb_buffer_pool_instances`, using multiple buffer pools was very important, yuo can read a good test case here:

**[MySQL Workload test](http://dimitrik.free.fr/blog/archives/2010/12/mysql-performance-analyzing-perconas-tpcclike-workload-on-mysql-55.html)**

Answer (score 0):

I have the problem in our test environment(Not set up by DBA).Finally I find there is one conf in my.cnf : sync_binlog=1. I change this conf to 0,and it works.
You can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to slow disk writes.

In our case it was because Debian GNU/Linux running mysqld was virtualised in Hyper-V, and even if it was given SSD storage `hdparm -t` was giving terrible results (10-20MB/s instead of 600MB/s that it gets on raw hardware)