# How can a simple MySQL insert/update be slower than an external web request?

Tags: php, mysql

Due to some performance issues I've been optimizing several SQL queries and adding indexes to certain tables/columns to speed up things.

Been running some time tests using `microtime()` in PHP (looping the queries a couple hundred times and calling `RESET QUERY CACHE` in each loop). I'm somewhat baffled by the results from one of the functions that does 3 things:

1. Inserts a row in a `sessions` table (InnoDB).
2. Updates a row in a `users` table (InnoDB).
3. Sends session ID to remote server which inserts the session ID in a session table of it's own (MongoDB).

Step 1. generally takes 30 - 40 ms, step 2. 20 - 30 ms and step 3. 7 - 20 ms.

I've tried looking up some expected query times for MySQL, but haven't found anything useful, so I don't know what to expect. Having said that, those query times seem somewhat high and I would definite **not** expect the web request to finish faster than the MySQL queries to the local database.

*Any idea if those query times are reasonable compared to the web request?*

**SQL/system information**

Both servers (the remote and the one with the MySQL database) are virtual servers running on the same physical server with shared storage (multiple SSD raid destup). The remote server has a single CPU and 2 GB RAM assigned, the MySQL server has 8 CPUs and 32 GB RAM assigned. Both servers are on the same LAN.

The `sessions` insert query:

```
 INSERT INTO sessions (
  session_id,
  user_id,
  application,
  machine_id,
  user_agent,
  ip,
  method,
  created,
  last_active,
  expires
)
VALUES (
  string, // session_id
  int, // user_id
  string, // application
  string, // machine_id
  string, // user_agent
  string, // ip
  string, // method
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, // created
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, // last_active
  NULL / FROM_UNIXTIME([PHP timestamp]) // expires
)
```

The `sessions` table (contains ~500'000 rows);

```
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| sessions_id | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| session_id  | char(32)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| user_id     | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| application | varchar(128)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| machine_id  | varchar(36)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_agent  | varchar(1024) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ip          | varchar(15)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| method      | varchar(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created     | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_active | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| expires     | datetime      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The `users` update query:

```
UPDATE users
SET last_active = string // For example '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
WHERE user_id = int
```

The `users` table (contains ~200'000 rows):

```
+------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id                | int(11)             | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username               | varchar(64)         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| first_name             | varchar(256)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name              | varchar(256)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| info                   | varchar(512)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address1               | varchar(512)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address2               | varchar(512)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city                   | varchar(256)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| zip_code               | varchar(128)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| state                  | varchar(256)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| country                | varchar(128)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| locale                 | varchar(5)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| phone                  | varchar(128)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email                  | varchar(256)        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| password               | char(60)            | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| permissions            | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| created                | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_active            | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: How big is the remote server DB?

Comment: The entire database is around 45 GB, but the session table is some 600'000 rows. I would just expect the socket and TCP overhead of the web request to be slower than writing/updating a few hundred bytes to the local MySQL.

Comment: Well the overheads for opening sockets, writing to them and getting data back are the same in both cases (since MySQL also is running as a service). The only difference is the query execution time and the transit time for the data. If the transit time is very low (quite likely with modern connections) then it boils down to which type of database can do it faster. Perhaps Mongo simply is faster for this sort of thing.

Comment: From personal testing I can say yes, Mongo will almost always outperform MySQL in an insert query. 20-30 ms for an update query writing a timestamp with a `WHERE` on a primary key still seems pretty slow though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was simply our MySQL settings (they were all default).

I ran a MySQL profile on the `users` update query and found that the step `query end` was taking up the majority of the time spent executing the query.

Googling that led me to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12446986/736247 - rather than using all the suggested values directly (which cannot be recommended, because some of them can have adverse effects on data integrity) I found some more info, including this page on Percona: https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/09/20/innodb-performance-optimization-basics-updated/.

InnoDB Startup Options and System Variables was also useful: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html was also useful.

I ended up setting new values for the following settings:

- `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`
- `innodb_flush_method`
- `innodb_buffer_pool_size`
- `innodb_buffer_pool_instances`
- `innodb_log_file_size`

This resulted in significantly shorter query times (measured in the same way as I did in the question):

1. Insert a row in a `sessions` table: ~8 ms (down from 30-40 ms).
2. Update a row in a `users` table: ~2.5 ms (down from 20-30 ms).